# 100% Memory usage on Azure App Service Plan with two Apps - working set used 10gb+

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I've got an app service plan with 14gb of memory - it should be plenty for my application's needs. There are two application services running on it, each identical - the private memory consumption of these hovers around 1gb but can spike to 4gb during periods of high usage. One app has a heavier usage pattern than the other.

Lately, during periods of high usage, I've noticed that the heavily used service can become unresponsive, and memory usage stays at 100% in the App Service Plan.

The high traffic service is using 4gb of private memory and starting to massively slow down. When I head over to the /scm.../ProcessExplorer/ page, I can see that the low traffic service has 1gb private memory used and 10gb of 'Working Set'.

As I understand it, on a single machine at least, the working set should be freed up when that memory is needed on another process. Does this happen naturally when two App Services share a single Plan?

It *looks* to me like the working set on the low-traffic instance is not being freed up to supply the needs of the high-traffic App Service.

If this is indeed the case, the simple fix is to move them to separate App Service Plans, each with 7gb of memory. However this seems like it might potentially be just shifting the problem around - has anyone else noticed similar issues with multiple Apps on a single App Service Plan? As far as I understand it, these shouldn't interfere with one another to the extent that they all need to be separated. Or have I got the wrong diagnosis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we solved this one via mitigation, rather than getting to the root cause.

We found a mitigation strategy to our previous memory issues several months ago, which was just to restart the server each night using a powershell script. This seems to prevent the memory just building up over time, and only costs us a few seconds of downtime. Our system doesn't have much overnight traffic as our users are all based in the same geographic location.

However we recently found that the overnight restart was reporting 'success' but actually failing each night due to expired credentials. Which meant that the memory issues we were having in the question I posted were actually exacerbated by server uptimes of several weeks. Restoring the overnight restart resolved the memory issues we were seeing, and we certainly don't see our system ever using 10gb+ again.

We'll investigate the memory issues if they rear their heads again. KetanChawda-MSFT's suggestion of using memory dumps to analyse the memory usage will be employed for this investigation when it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

In some high memory-consumption scenarios, your app might truly require more computing resources. In that case, consider scaling to a higher service tier so the application gets all the resources it needs. Other times, a bug in the code might cause a memory leak. A coding practice also might increase memory consumption. Getting insight into what's triggering high memory consumption is a two-part process. First, create a process dump, and then analyze the process dump. Crash Diagnoser from the Azure Site Extension Gallery can efficiently perform both these steps. For more information.

**refer** [Capture and analyze a dump file for intermittent high memory for Web Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2016/02/02/how-to-capture-and-analyze-dump-for-intermittent-high-memory-on-azure-web-app/).