# Why are my Python Azure apps taking so much memory in an app service plan?

Tags: python, azure, memory, azure-app-service-plans

In an Azure Service plan with operating system Linux and Pricing Tier "Premium V2 (P1v2:1)" I have memory issues. It only has three Python apps (2 web apps (APIs) and 1 function app (with TimeTrigger)) which are constantly using 65 to 67% of the memory available for the Azure Service Plan. When comparing this to the performance of C# applications it easily takes 15 apps to get the same memory usage.

I'm wondering how I can get a better understanding of why this is the case and perhaps some tips on solving this issue.

**Memory percentage usage of the Linux Azure App Service**
[image: Memory percentage usage of the Linux Azure App Service]

Comment: You can refer to this answer by Ketan to check intermittent High Memory usage on Azure Web App: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58989835/15969115